# python 3 notify2 иконка на кнопке

Tags: python

Можно ли в notify создать кнопки с иконками, например оповещение о входящем звонке с телефона: снять, положить трубку.

Comment: я пробовал 7 лет назад, не получилось)

Comment: Notification.add_action()?

Comment: Ну так я делал.. как добавить к action ещё иконку?